# All asynchronous calls succeed or none, how to handle

Tags: swift, asynchronous, closures

I'm trying to create an online mobile application and can't figure out the best way to handle functions with multiple asynchronous calls. Say I have a function for example that updates a user in some way, but involved multiple asynchronous calls in the single function call. So for example:

```
// Function caller
update(myUser) { (updatedUser, error) in
    if let error = error {
       // Present some error UI to the user
    }

    if let updatedUser = updatedUser {
       // Do something with the user
    }
} 


// Function implementation
public func updateUser(user: User, completion: @escaping (User?, Error?) -> () {

    // asynchronous call A
    updateUserTable(user: User) { error in
        if let error = error {
           completion(nil, error)
        } else {
           // create some new user object
           completion(user, nil)
        }
    }

    // asynchronous call B
    uploadMediaForUser(user: User) { error in
        if let error = error {
           completion(nil, error)
        }
    }

    // asynchronous call C
    removeOldReferenceForUser(user: User) { error in
         if let error = error {
           completion(nil, error)
        }
    }

    // Possibly any additional amount of asynchronous calls...
}
```

In a case like this, where one function call like updating a user involved multiple asynchronous calls, is this an all or nothing situation? Say for example the updateUserTable() call completes, but the user disconnects from the internet as uploadMediaForUser() was running, and that throws an error. Since updateUserTable() completed fine, my function caller thinks this method succeeded when in fact not everything involved in updating the user completed. Now I'm stuck with a user that might have mismatched references or wrong information in my database because the user's connection dropped mid call.

How do I handle this all or nothing case? If EVERY asynchronous call completed without an error, I know updating the user was a success. If only a partial amount of asynchronous calls succeeded and some failed, this is BAD and I need to either undo the changes that succeeded or attempt the failed methods again.

What do I do in this scenario? And also, and how do I use my completion closure to help identify the actions needed depending on the success or failure of the method. Did all them succeed? Good, tell the user. Do some succeed and some failed? Bad, revert changes or try again (i dont know)??

Edit:

Just calling my completion with the error doesn't seem like enough. Sure the user sees that something failed, but that doesn't help with the application knowing the steps needed to fix the damage where partial changes were made.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding helper enums for your tasks and returned result, things like (User?, Error?) have a small ambiguity of the case when for example both are nil? or you have the User and the Error set, is it a success or not?

Regarding the all succeeded or some failed - I would suggest using the DispatchGroup to notify when all tasks finished (and check how they finished in the end).

Also from you current code, when some request fails it's not clear for which user - as you pass nil, so it might bring difficulties in rolling it back after failure.

So in my point of view something like below (not tested the code, but think you should catch the idea from it) could give you control about the issues you described:

```
public enum UpdateTask {
    case userTable
    case mediaUpload
    // ... any more tasks you need
}

public enum UpdateResult {
    case success
    case error([UpdateTask: Error])
}

// Function implementation
public func updateUser(user: User, completion: @escaping (User, UpdateResult) -> ()) {

    let updateGroup = DispatchGroup()
    var tasksErrors = [UpdateTask: Error]()

    // asynchronous call A
    updateGroup.enter()
    updateUserTable(user: User) { error in
        if let error = error {
            tasksErrors[.userTable] = error
        }
        updateGroup.leave()
    }

    // ... any other similar tasks here

    updateGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global()) { // Choose the Queue that suits your needs here by yourself
        if tasksErrors.isEmpty {
            completion(user, .success)
        } else {
            completion(user, .error(tasksErrors))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a “previous” version of everything changed, then if something failed revert back to the “previous” versions. Only change UI once all returned without failure, and if one failed, revert to “previous” version.

EX:

```
var temporary = “userName”
getChanges(fromUser) {
If error {
   userName = temporary //This reverts back due to failure.
  }
}
```